# Comparing the year to the year part of a date in the database

Tags: java, javascript, mysql

I have an employee registration form where the employee adds his details.

When click on the `Submit` button I'm adding default holidays to the employee from the back end. I have a table `holiday` in my database which contains the general holidays for every year.
When the employee registers the holidays for the current year alone should be added to the `employee_holiday` table.

Can anyone tell me how do I compare the current year with that of the date in holiday table and add it to the `employee_holiday` table?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not one in the same, and you cannot update MySQL with JavaScript alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood clearly your problem but as far as MySQL query is concerned you can use this query to select current year's holidays:

```
SELECT *
FROM holidays 
WHERE date_format(now(), '%Y') = date_format(holiday_date, '%Y');
```

assuming table `holiday` has a column called `holiday_date` as the date of the holidays.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of a way in java you can compare date.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
if(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)==2012){
    System.out.println("Same year");
}
```